# how to customize an image view and textview?

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview

i have a listview and the row model/design should be something as shown in the image below.

My question is, how can I design a view to appear as shown in the image in the the third row?? I want to design something like the blue rectangular shape with round corners and then write the value on it as shown in the image

Is it a textview or imageView? Please advice how can i design such a view.

**image**:

[image]

Comment: Take one textview and set drawable right of textview and set maxems = 5 or whatever you want and set rounded background

Comment: you can implement this as a textview.You will have to give it the back ground by making a selector resource file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a **TextView** and give it a **Shape**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >         
   <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@color/common_border_color" />

  <solid android:color="replace with blue color" />

  <padding
       android:left="1dp"
       android:right="1dp"
       android:top="1dp" />

  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  </shape>
```

Make this in an xml called **rounded_corner.xml** in the drawable folder.

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use textview and as a background of text view use below xml

rounded_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#abcdef" >
    </solid>
    <corners
        android:radius="20dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In your drawable create one xml file and add this code in that

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<padding
    android:top="3dp"
    android:left="8dp"
    android:right="8dp"
    android:bottom="3dp"/>

<solid android:color="#00796B" />

 <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
```

```
In your view(Button/TextView) add background, some ex code

 <Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/delete"
     android:text="Ur text"/>
```